# I got this error in my xml file : 'error: attribute altsrc not found.'

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am getting the error from my xml file below, and I can't figure out what went wrong :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_welcome_scene"
    tools:context=".ui.onboarding.WelcomeActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/onboaring_title1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/welcome_banner"
        android:contentDescription="@string/banner_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_onboardingDesc_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:text="@string/onboarding_desc_1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tint="@color/main_purple"
        app:altsrc="@drawable/ic_circle_full_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/menu2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_onboardingDesc_1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_24" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tint="@color/main_purple"
        app:altsrc="@drawable/ic_circle_full_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/menu3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/menu1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/menu1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_24" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tint="@color/main_purple"
        app:altsrc="@drawable/ic_circle_full_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/menu2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/menu2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_24" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

And it seems to be coming from the `app:altsrc` attribute on my `ImageFilterView`. But there's no error or warning message in the xml file while I'm editing them. I can't find out why I got this error. Can anyone help me find out why? Here's the build error message :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `altSrc` (capital `S`) as the official documentation says [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/utils/widget/ImageFilterView#imagefilterview-attributes):

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know why I missed that capital S. Thank you for your help!